# Please Reopen this Question: "Using Chord iii in a Chord Progression (Major Key)"

Tags: discussion

Link to question: [Using chord iii in a chord progression (major key)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84847/using-chord-iii-in-a-chord-progression-major-key)

---

This question was apparently a great question that I decided to answer it.  However, before I even **typed** a character, the question was **closed** as off-topic.

> [image: IT'S CLOSED!!!!!!!!!!]

I think the OP is trying to find **examples of chord progressions**, and **not** songs.  However, I don't have the privilege to cast close and reopen votes.  I can raise recommended closure flags if I want a question to be closed, but it seems like if there isn't any way to reopen questions, though.  So I am writing this post here.

Can we reopen this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally agree that the question is fine, and have voted to reopen.

The main question here is "I read somewhere that generally chord iii is not used, or very rarely used. Is this correct?"

I think that this question can be answered well (indeed it has been), and that any sensible answer would either include examples of its use, or give the OP the means to find them.

I don't think the question is at heart about "finding a particular song", so I don't think that close reason works very well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I mentioned the word "examples", I actually meant examples of chord *iii* being used in a chord progression. However, it has been misinterpreted to be examples of "songs only". I wanted to edit the question later, but it was already closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Grace - You can vote to reopen the question if you didn't do so as well.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya I have done so.

Comment: Then that's good.

Answer (score 2):

No, for a few reasons:

1. The OP explicitly asks in that question for example songs.
2. Five members of the community voted to close it.
3. Once you have sufficient rep for reopen votes, you can vote to reopen questions. That is the correct route to do this.

Comment: I have edited my question now to explain clearly what I actually meant. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Grace - that made all the difference.

Comment: Should have cleared the confusion by editing it earlier itself. Better late than never!